# woocommerce multiple custom fields code

Tags: php, html

I used a guide to add multiple custom fields to the general tab in product post setting.

When I enter data into the fields, it saves and shows on product page without problem;
The problem is that when I erase them, data cleaned from fields but created divs and other html elements remain on the product page.

This is the code I used in 
**functions.php** in my theme folder:

```
// Custom field Type

?> <p class="form-field custom_field_type">
    <label for="custom_field_type"><?php echo __( 'ویژگی های کلیدی محصول', 'woocommerce' ); ?></label>
    <span class="wrap">
        <?php $custom_field_type = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_custom_field_type', true ); ?>  
        <input placeholder="<?php _e( '', 'woocommerce' ); ?>" type="text" name="_field_one" value="<?php echo $custom_field_type[0]; ?>" step="any" min="0" />
        <input placeholder="<?php _e( '', 'woocommerce' ); ?>" type="text" name="_field_two" value="<?php echo $custom_field_type[1]; ?>" step="any" min="0" />
        <input placeholder="<?php _e( '', 'woocommerce' ); ?>" type="text" name="_field_three" value="<?php echo $custom_field_type[2]; ?>" step="any" min="0" />
        <input placeholder="<?php _e( '', 'woocommerce' ); ?>" type="text" name="_field_four" value="<?php echo $custom_field_type[3]; ?>" step="any" min="0" />
        <input placeholder="<?php _e( '', 'woocommerce' ); ?>" type="text" name="_field_five" value="<?php echo $custom_field_type[4]; ?>" step="any" min="0" />
        <input placeholder="<?php _e( '', 'woocommerce' ); ?>" type="text" name="_field_six" value="<?php echo $custom_field_type[5]; ?>" step="any" min="0" />
    </span>
    <span class="description"><?php _e( 'شش ویژگی کلیدی محصول را بنویسید', 'woocommerce' ); ?></span> </p> <?php
```

and for **saving** also in **functions.php**:

```
// Custom Field
$custom_field_type = array(
    esc_attr( $_POST['_field_one'] ), esc_attr( $_POST['_field_two'] ),
    esc_attr( $_POST['_field_three'] ), esc_attr( $_POST['_field_four'] ),
    esc_attr( $_POST['_field_five'] ), esc_attr( $_POST['_field_six'] )
);
update_post_meta( $post_id, '_custom_field_type', $custom_field_type );
```

in the **single-product.php** for shownig:

```
  <?php
       if (!empty( $custom_field_type = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_custom_field_type', true))) {
    echo '<div id="vijegiha">';
      echo '<h3 id="vijegih3">ویژگی های کلیدی</h3>';
        echo '<ul>';
            foreach($custom_field_type as $vijegi)
            if (!empty( $vijegi )) {
                 echo '<li>'.$vijegi.'</li>';}
        echo '</ul>';
    echo '</div>';}else{} ?>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. I've improved your post mostly in terms of grammar, but it still has a problem with the description of the issue. Please try to clarify the last (and the most important) phrase: be sure to describe the expected and the actual behaviour and describe them in such a way that it's simple to reproduce them. Also, you probably should add a link to the guide you refer to in the beginning. Best regards

Comment: Sorry for my english. Thanks

Comment: Navid, you are welcome, but please also improve the description like I suggested above

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your $custom_field_type might be an empty array so you could try with this:

```
<?php
if (!empty( $custom_field_type = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_custom_field_type', true))) {
    if(count($custom_field_type) > 0){
        echo '<div id="vijegiha">';
          echo '<h3 id="vijegih3">ویژگی های کلیدی</h3>';
            echo '<ul>';
                foreach($custom_field_type as $vijegi)
                if (!empty( $vijegi )) {
                     echo '<li>'.$vijegi.'</li>';}
            echo '</ul>';
        echo '</div>';
    }
}else{} ?>
```

Comment: Doesn't work. Html elements are there even If there is nothing in fields.

Comment: @NavidM What do you get if you var_dump($custom_field_type)?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it:

```
<?php
$custom_field_type = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_custom_field_type', true);
$custom_field_type = array_filter($custom_field_type, 'strlen');
if (count($custom_field_type)) {
        echo '<div id="vijegiha">';
          echo '<h3 id="vijegih3">ویژگی های کلیدی</h3>';
            echo '<ul>';
                foreach($custom_field_type as $vijegi)
                if (!empty( $vijegi )) {
                     echo '<li>'.$vijegi.'</li>';}
            echo '</ul>';
        echo '</div>';
}else{} ?>
```

now it works correctly.